# Rails 5 - Cannot initialize ActionCable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I just upgraded my app to Rails 5, I'm following a tutorial about ActionCable basics, but I cannot start a server.

Everytime I try to do so, I get the following error:

`uninitialized constant ActionCable (NameError)`

It seems like it comes from my `routes.rb` file, from this line :

`mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'`

This line is specified in every tutorial I've read so far, so I assume it is required for Actioncable to work. Has anyone encountered this problem before ? My gemfile is up-to-date, i'm using rails 5.0.0.1

Comment: Given that your Gemfile has Rails5, it should work - do you get the same error if you launch the server through bundler (e.g., `bundle exec rails s`)?

Comment: @gmcnaughton yes, exact same error

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that you are declaring the channel and connection files in the correct place, then make sure you are loading ActionCable in `config/application.rb`.

You may have something like the following in this file:

```
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
# require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

In which case you just need to add `require "action_cable/engine"`.

Or, if you prefer you can use `require "rails/all"` to load all the frameworks as once. The [Rails Initialization Process guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html#railties-lib-rails-all-rb)
 has more detail about this.

`rails/all` loads the following:

```
  active_record/railtie
  action_controller/railtie
  action_view/railtie
  action_mailer/railtie
  active_job/railtie
  action_cable/engine
  rails/test_unit/railtie
  sprockets/railtie
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34396006/uninitialized-constant-actioncableserverconfigurationapplicationcable) answer, make sure you have followed the following file path. You need `app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb` that look like this.

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Channel < ActionCable::Channel::Base
  end
end
```

and `app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb`

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
  end
end
```

Comment: Nope, both files look just like this.